# Trying to batch process videos in multi-depth subdirectories with ffmpeg, find with -exec

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

The sub-directories have different depth and have videos scattered. I am using find command to locate videos of multiple extensions like mp4, mkv, m4v, webm, ts, mov, etc. and then trying to process them with ffmpeg.

So far, I have come up with this command:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.webm" -o -name "*.ts" -o -name "*.mov" \) -execdir ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec libx264 -crf 32 -vf scale=1280:720 -r 16 -map_metadata -1 {}.mp4 \;
```

If I try adding a prefix to ffmpeg output as `... out{}.mp4 \;`, it is not possible. It says:

> out./<FILE_NAME>.mp4: No such file or directory

I want the final output to have `"out${original_name}".mp4` as the name. Is there anyway to add prefix to output?

Comment: You always pass to ffmpeg the same filename `$1.mp4` where $1 is the first parameter of your script. Instead you should tell ffmpeg to use an output file based on the name of the input file.

Comment: Instead of invoking `ffmpeg` directly from `-exec`, I would use an auxiliary shell script, which is called by `find` and which in turn invokes `ffmpeg`. It costs you one more child process for each input file, but it makes the whole thing easier to debug, because you decouple the generation of the files to be converted, from the actual conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to add prefix to output?

Yes, use a shell script like this:

```
find . ... -exec sh -c '
for src; do
  name=${src##*/}
  dest=${src%"$name"}out${name%.*}.mp4
  ffmpeg -i "$src" ... "$dest"
done' sh {} +
```

Comment: can you explain how arguments from `find` are taken into for loop's `src`? i am bit confused.

Comment: @rogerD `-exec ... {} +` runs `...` with selected files as arguments, `sh -c '...' sh 1 2 3` evaluates `...` as a shell script with `1 2 3` as positional parameters, `for src; do` is syntactic sugar for `for src in "$@"; do`, where `$@` expands to positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is the first argument to your currently running shell, and probably empty.

You are probably looking for something like

```
find . -type f \(
   -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.m4v" \
   -o -name "*.webm" -o -name "*.ts" -o -name "*.mov" \) \
   -exec sh -c 'for f; do
      ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec libx264 -crf 32 -vf scale=1280:720 \
         -r 16 -map_metadata -1 "${f%.*}".mp4;
    done' _ {} +
```

The use of `-exec sh -c '...'` allows you to refer to the argument repeatedly and apply the shell's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) facilities etc, and the `for` loop and the `+` instead of `\;` is just an efficiency hack to allow you to `-exec` fewer times.

Comment: It will probably still fail for the `mp4` case but it should not be hard to add a simple temporary file and subsequent `mv`

Comment: i realised that find replaces `{}` with arguments. Now I have updated the original question. The only problem that remains is adding a prefix before mentioning `{}` in the output of ffmpeg.

Comment: With `-exec ... \;` it replaces exactly one name, but yeah. Slightly miffed that you changed the question to be about something else than you originally asked; the proper procedure would be to (accept the answer for the question you actually asked, and) ask a new question.